# Problems installing ubuntu on a lenovo thinkpad x1 yoga

Tags: uefi, live-usb, lenovo, touchscreen, 16.04

I'm trying to install ubuntu gnome 16.04 beta on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 yoga. I'm interested in getting gnome 3.18 (or 3.20) for the touchscreen and wacom support. Sadly, I don't have any previous experience with UEFI, and I can't get the laptop to boot a live session.

I'll appreciate any help, as the X1 yoga is a beauty, but I hate Windows 10.

Comment: Why can't you? Are you trying to boot DVD or flash drive?

Comment: I'm trying to boot from live USB. I tried a couple of distros (new and older) to no avail. My guess is that I'm missing some BIOS permission to boot on a usb. I get to grub but then it wont' boot to live.

Comment: If I'm right, in the UEFI ("BIOS") in the Boot menu you can set device boot priority. Set the USB drive's priority to an option which contains "UEFI". Save and exit.

Comment: Also here is a thorough guide regarding UEFI installations - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Comment: I've added your edits with your solution as an answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

From the original poster's edits (now removed from their question):

> SOLVED: You need to disable pstate by adding an instruction in GRUB:
>
> ```
> intel_pstate=disable
> ```
>
> Then do it again at GRUB after installation. This is due to a reappearing
>   bug that's going to be fixed at kernel 4.5 ([Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1188647))

Comment: Where is GRUB inside Windows 10? How does one change this intel_pstate from inside Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try live linu installer or universal usb installer.  (Make sure you install from the real websites).  I had a problem booting in legacy if i made a usb without either of these two programs.  Uefi works without these programs, but it is best to get legacy working for dual boot.  You must use the key for boot order.  My acer is f12. Usually escape, fb fb or f12.  Try.